# Inject Guice on a static final property?

Tags: guice

I have many named annotated instances of a TabularResultSet class I want to pass to multiple classes to a static final property. How do I inject this? I dont think it is liking the final and static nature of the property. Must I call the injector directly in the property declaration to assign the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to get Guice to inject into static fields. See [Static Injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections) in the Guice documentation.

But I'm not sure about `static final`. `final` fields also carry the guarantee that they are initialized exactly once (unless reflection is used). Guice may be able to work around this by using reflection (I know it's possible for Guice to inject into `@Inject private final` fields using reflection), but that's a pretty dirty solution. If the value of a field is ever set outside a static initialization block (for `static`) or a constructor (for non-`static` fields) then it shouldn't have `final`.

But even if it is possible, it's not a good idea. Static state is the opposite of dependency injection. Dependency injection is based on the Hollywood Principle: "don't call us, we'll call you". You're not supposed to *look up* a value from Guice, you're supposed to just declare that you need it, and Guice will supply it to you.

Comment: hmmm... many of my class designs often involve the class representing an instance of something, and all the instances are maintained in a static final collection that is imported from a database. This design has always been successful for me. But maybe Guice doesn't work here or I am not creating an optimal setup.

Comment: You can have a collection imported from a database, just don't make it a static collection. Instead, bind it using a Guice module and inject it where you need it. You can even make it a Guice `@Singleton` if you want only one instance -- but if you inject it into classes that need it (rather than looking it up from a static field) then you have the freedom to substitute with non-singleton state in the future (or, more usefully, in tests).

Comment: @ThomasN. if the data is imported from a database, then you want to inject a class that accesses the data (possibly caching it or lazy loading it), not the data itself. Your Guice modules shouldn't do something as slow as accessing a database